# SPWX - this is found as a suffix on many user names

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

This is my first meta question and is a little trivial.  I just wondered why a number of usernames have this format: Username_SPWX.

What does it mean?  Do they all work for the same company or something?  If you go to [Users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users) and search on SPWX you'll see what I mean.  I don't suppose there is anything dodgy with these accounts.

Comment: Thank you @Tally for this note, we also noted that but there no type of dodgy with these accounts yet. but we still waiting to hear from them What does it mean?

Comment: Hi Mohamed, thanks for the reply.  I was thinking it could be a company name, the SP part suggests Sharepoint, I also could not find out anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image added to [this reply](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231168/automatic-redirect-to-sharepoint-mobile-app/232815#232815) says `ChinaSoft Team Site`. So my best bet is that there are some employees/consultants behind those accounts from the company "ChinaSoft International" that are sharing their knowledge.